# Unable to execute the windows bash script on Jenkins slave

Tags: windows, google-chrome, jenkins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-agent

As a part of regression testing need to run the bash script on windows machine which actually open the chrome browser and traverse the website and generate the test report.

when i try to execute it through jenkins all the test cases are getting failed as its unable to open the browser, the same is getting passed when we logon to the remote windows server and execute the script manually.

**NOTE:** Have provided the same credentials on jenkins slave windows service

found below log on event manager

> Activation of app Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy!CortanaUI failed with error: This app can't be activated by the Built-in Administrator. See the Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational log for additional information.

[image: Jenkins slave service config]

Could you please help me here..

Answer (score 1):

Hi can you enable the option **Allow service to interact with desktop** for the jenkins slave service on your windows slave machine.

You can enable it by going In services.msc > right click on service name > Properties > Log On > Allow service to interact with desktop

Comment: NO have tried with this no luck. same issue while doing this as well